# Restlets GAE Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm unable to run [the following Android sample](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html).
http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html

I'm using Eclipse Juno 4.2 on a 64Bit Ubuntu 12.10 and trying to deploy on api Level 15 (Android 4.03 Emulator and real Device)

I just imported the sample project in my workspace (Android Project from existing source) and added org.restlet.jar (from restlet-android-2.0.15) to my classpath as described above.

At the following line I get an exception:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(
    "http://restlet-example-serialization.appspot.com/contacts/123");
```

Exception:

> `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
>   `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.restlet.resource.ClientResource`

Can someone please guide me on how I can solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it run but its not really clear to me.

I removed the org.restlet.jar from my classpath and added the source folder instead.

Comment: To link the source folder only moved my problem since I now need the Codehaus-Jackson libs for more complex serialisation and therefor is no code attached in the SDK